# How do I loop and append my code to a CSV file? - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, append, export-to-csv

I'm brand new to coding, I've been working on this for about a week and hit a dead end so please be gentle.

What I'm looking to do is get all the data from the url in the format that the print statement is displaying and put that into a CSV file.

I've managed to successfully print a single line, but I've got no idea how I get that to loop through all the other lines and append them to a CSV file. Any hints or tips?

```
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')

import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification_%E2%80%93_CAF_First_Round"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

dateLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "bday dtstart published updated"})
timeLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "mobile-float-reset ftime"})
homeTeamLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "fhome"})
awayTeamLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "faway"})
scoreLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "fscore"})
venueLists = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"itemprop" : "name address"})

date = dateLists[0].text.strip()
time = timeLists[0].text.strip()
homeTeam = homeTeamLists[0].text.strip()
awayTeam = awayTeamLists[0].text.strip()
score = scoreLists[0].text.strip()
venue = venueLists[0].text.strip()

print(date, time, homeTeam, score, awayTeam, venue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to iterate through each item in the list. You can use `enumerate` to get the index position and then use that to append each item into a list and for the dataframe:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification_%E2%80%93_CAF_First_Round"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

dateLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "bday dtstart published updated"})
timeLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "mobile-float-reset ftime"})
homeTeamLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "fhome"})
awayTeamLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "faway"})
scoreLists = soup.find_all(attrs={"class" : "fscore"})
venueLists = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"itemprop" : "name address"})


dateList = []
timeList = []
homeTeamList = []
awayTeamList = []
scoreList = []
venueList = []

for idx, v in enumerate(dateLists):

    dateList.append(dateLists[idx].text.strip())
    timeList.append(timeLists[idx].text.strip())
    homeTeamList.append(homeTeamLists[idx].text.strip())
    awayTeamList.append(awayTeamLists[idx].text.strip())
    scoreList.append(scoreLists[idx].text.strip())
    venueList.append(venueLists[idx].text.strip())
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dateList,
                   'time':timeList,
                   'home':homeTeamList,
                   'away':awayTeamList,
                   'score':scoreList,
                   'venue':venueList})
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
          date         time                   home                   away         score                                              venue
0   2019-09-04  16:00 UTC+3               Ethiopia                Lesotho           0–0                       Bahir Dar Stadium, Bahir Dar
1   2019-09-08  15:00 UTC+2                Lesotho               Ethiopia           1–1                            Setsoto Stadium, Maseru
2   2019-09-05  18:00 UTC+3                Somalia               Zimbabwe           1–0  El Hadj Hassan Gouled Aptidon Stadium, Djibout...
3   2019-09-10  15:00 UTC+2               Zimbabwe                Somalia           3–1                    National Sports Stadium, Harare
4   2019-09-04  16:00 UTC+3                Eritrea                Namibia           1–2                             Denden Stadium, Asmara
5   2019-09-10  19:00 UTC+2                Namibia                Eritrea           2–0                       Sam Nujoma Stadium, Windhoek
6   2019-09-04  15:00 UTC+2                Burundi               Tanzania           1–1          Prince Louis Rwagasore Stadium, Bujumbura
7   2019-09-08  16:00 UTC+3               Tanzania                Burundi  1–1 (a.e.t.)                    National Stadium, Dar es Salaam
8   2019-09-04  18:00 UTC+3               Djibouti               Eswatini           2–1    El Hadj Hassan Gouled Aptidon Stadium, Djibouti
9   2019-09-10  15:00 UTC+2               Eswatini               Djibouti           0–0                      Mavuso Sports Centre, Manzini
10  2019-09-07  16:00 UTC+2               Botswana                 Malawi           0–0                   Francistown Stadium, Francistown
11  2019-09-10  14:00 UTC+2                 Malawi               Botswana           1–0                           Kamuzu Stadium, Blantyre
12  2019-09-06  17:00 UTC±0                 Gambia                 Angola           0–1                        Independence Stadium, Bakau
13  2019-09-10  16:00 UTC+1                 Angola                 Gambia           2–1                     Estádio 11 de Novembro, Luanda
14  2019-09-04  18:00 UTC±0                Liberia           Sierra Leone           3–1      Samuel Kanyon Doe Sports Complex, Paynesville
15  2019-09-08  16:30 UTC±0           Sierra Leone                Liberia           1–0                    Siaka Stevens Stadium, Freetown
16  2019-09-04  18:30 UTC+4              Mauritius             Mozambique           0–1                           Stade Anjalay, Belle Vue
17  2019-09-10  16:00 UTC+2             Mozambique              Mauritius           2–0                         Estádio do Zimpeto, Maputo
18  2019-09-04  15:30 UTC±0  São Tomé and Príncipe          Guinea-Bissau           0–1             Estádio Nacional 12 de Julho, São Tomé
19  2019-09-10  16:30 UTC±0          Guinea-Bissau  São Tomé and Príncipe           2–1                     Estádio 24 de Setembro, Bissau
20  2019-09-04  16:00 UTC+2            South Sudan      Equatorial Guinea           1–1         Al-Hilal Stadium, Omdurman (Sudan)[note 2]
21  2019-09-08  17:00 UTC+1      Equatorial Guinea            South Sudan           1–0                    Nuevo Estadio de Malabo, Malabo
22  2019-09-06  15:00 UTC+3                Comoros                   Togo           1–1                            Stade de Moroni, Moroni
23  2019-09-10  16:00 UTC±0                   Togo                Comoros           2–0                               Stade de Kégué, Lomé
24  2019-09-05  15:30 UTC+1                   Chad                  Sudan           1–3    Stade Omnisports Idriss Mahamat Ouya, N'Djamena
25  2019-09-10  19:00 UTC+2                  Sudan                   Chad           0–0                       Al-Merrikh Stadium, Omdurman
26  2019-09-05  16:00 UTC+4             Seychelles                 Rwanda           0–3                             Stade Linité, Victoria
27  2019-09-10  18:00 UTC+2                 Rwanda             Seychelles           7–0                  Stade Régional Nyamirambo, Kigali
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything I was trying was coming back with `Did you call find_all()` type errors. This is also the first time I've come across `enumerate` since I've been scouring the web to find an answer. Could I ask one more quick question, why did you use `v` on row 24?

Comment: Oh, just habit of iterating through dictionaries. I usually use k, v (key, value). So just used v for value. You could call whatever makes sense to you though.